# Gulp exclude folder containg an underscore ('_')

Tags: gulp, filepath, src, taskmanager

Is it possible to exclude folders containt an underscore?

I tried this:

```
gulp.task( 'updateLayout', function () {
    return gulp.src( [targetPath + '/layout/**/*.ai', '!'+targetPath+'/layout/_**/'] )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'layout' ) );
} )
```

But its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the exclusion glob pattern, you just need to add the `*.*` at the end. So it would mean to exclude any file in any folder that starts with an _

```
gulp.task( 'updateLayout', function () {
    return gulp.src( [targetPath + '/layout/**/*.ai', '!'+targetPath+'/layout/_**/*.*'] )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'layout' ) );
} )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed, but in my case it works like this: gulp doesn't copy images inside folders "*_" but the folder is copied (as empty).

Comment: I know this is very late, however adding `, { nodir: true }` as a final argument in src will omit the empty directories.